# Is it possible to explore SVN repo as an ordinary folder in Windows (for examle, mount as remote drive)?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, webdav

So, I need to make a file storage for our team. Also I have SVN server. Opportunity to do rollbacks and control on who created or deleted file is very neccessary and important for our project.

Any ideas? Maybe without SVN. I can connect using WebDAV but only in read-only mode (because there is no LOCKS support in it).

Comment: Have you tried [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertechnologies.com/products/webdrive/WebDAVClient.html), which can mount WebDav shares as "real" drives? (Note: I'm not affiliated in any way.) See this blog of someone who was successful with this combo: http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.ch/2011/01/mapping-drive-letter-to-subversion.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the SVN server to allow exactly that.
Read the chapter in the SVN book about [WebDAV and Autoversioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.webdav.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want is the ability to roll back changes, and limit who can make the changes, but without the bother of checking in and out files?

Maybe Subversion isn't for you. I've done similar sharing with [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) and there's now [BoxNet](http://box.com) that's suppose to be like Dropbox on Steroids. Dropbox (and I assume box.net too) has some features that are very nice:

- You can setup folder sharing between particular teams. That way, you can say who can and cannot access these files.
- Dropbox automatically saves each and every version of a file, so you can always go back to previous versions -- even if that file has been deleted.
- Files are stored locally. All a user has to know is to save a particular file in a particular folder, and everyone has access to it. I've successfully used Dropbox to collaborate with managers that make the Pointed Hair boss in Dilbert look like a high tech genius.

There's also [Skydrive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/home) and [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/start#home), but I don't find them as universal as Dropbox or as easy to use. It's possible to use Dropbox without ever going to the Dropbox website. To the non-geek, it appears to be magic as files I've written and edited appear on their drive. It took me a few weeks to train one person that he didn't have to email me his document when he made changes because I already had it.

Dropbox gives you 2 Gb of space for free which doesn't sound like a lot. However, my first hard drive was a whopping 20Mb which was twice the size of the standard 10Mb drive at that time. If you're not storing a lot of multimedia presentations or doing a lot of Photoshop, 2Gb might be more than enough for your project.

I know Windows 7 and later has some sort of [versioning system](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11130/restore-previous-versions-of-files-in-every-edition-of-windows-7/) built into it. I know this because anytime someone mentions that Mac OS X has time machine, some Wingeek pipes in stating that Windows has the same thing, but only better!. Unfortunately, Windows is not my forte, so I don't know too much about this specific feature. I believe the default is once per day, but it can be changed. This might be the perfect solution if everyone is on Windows.

Subversion can do autoversioning as [Stefan stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348043/368630). Considering his position in the Subversion community (especially his work on TortoiseSVN), he knows his stuff. Unfortunately I don't know too much about it since I've never used or seen this feature implemented. It's probably due to the fact that I work mainly with developers who know what a version control system is, and therefore have no need for something that does the versioning for them.

Also don't forget to check if you can use your corporate Sharepoint which does something very much what you want. I am not too impressed with Sharepoint, but if the facility is there, and your company can give you the support, it is something you probably want to look into.